# Is there a Pythonic way of calling many members of a single object?

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to rewrite this Pythonically:

```
if not x.v1()
  if not x.v2()
    if not x.v3()
      return 'validated'
return 'invalid'
```

Note in particular that if `x.v1()` does not pass, `x.v2()` and `x.v3()` are not even run.

This is the best idea I have so far:

```
import operator

for method in ['v1', 'v2', 'v3']:
  if operator.methodcaller(method)(x):
    return 'invalid'
return 'validated'
```

but I feel like there's definitely a more Pythonic way.

**Clarification:** The number of functions is large and possibly even changeable at runtime, so though `x.v1() or x.v2() or x.v3()` certainly looks nicer, it's not possible and the array is indeed necessary. (That said, if there's a better way than writing it with all these strings, tell me about it!) Sorry about the unclearness.

Answer (score 5):

Just invert the logic.

```
if x.v1() or x.v2() or x.v3():
  return 'invalid'
return 'validated'
```

Comment: This is actually easier to read than the `all` or `any` version.

Answer (score 1):

If you are thinking about supporting arbitrary number of functions, it's worth rolling out your own version of `any` and `all` for a list of methods:

```
def any_fn(*funcs):
    return any(f() for f in funcs)

def all_fn(*funcs):
    return all(f() for f in funcs)
```

Then you can say:

```
if any_fn(x.v1, x.v2, x.v3):
    return 'invalid'
else:
    return 'valid'
```

Answer (score 0):

> Note in particular that **if x.v1() does not pass**, x.v2() and x.v3() are
>   not even run.

I think you mean "if **not x.v1()** does not pass, x.v2() and x.v3() are not even run." Which is the same as "If x.v1() passes, x.v2() and x.v3() are not even run" ... and 'invalid' is returned. Since Python short-circuits expression evaluation, the following is a Pythonic way of rewriting the code in the OP with the stated intent of short-circuited evauation:

```
if x.v1() or x.v2() or x.v3():
    return 'invalid'
else:
    return 'validated'
```